# Cannot access ProgressBar from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I got a simple application that downloads a file. But I cannot access the ProgressBar decared in MainActivity from AsyncTask class. The code is:

```java
class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

    protected Long doInBackground(String... genx) {
        while(...) {
            publishProgress((int)(total * 100 / filelen));
        }
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mPB.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }
    ...
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar mPB;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mPB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your `ProgressBar` in constructer `DownloadFilesTask`

```
class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

    private ProgressBar mPB;

    DownloadFilesTask(ProgressBar mPB) {
        this.mPB = mPB;
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(String... genx) {
        while(...) {
            publishProgress((int)(total * 100 / filelen));
        }
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mPB.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: The code compiled but when running the progress bar doesn't work :-(

Comment: You are setting the constructor when initializing DownloadFilesTask?

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't really mean much. care to detail what issue you are facing with this solution?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't call setContentView(..) in onCreate(...)

Comment: that's unrelated to the question

Comment: can you please tell me how its unrelated? Because if the view isn't set, then how will the ProgressBar be created? If you notice the code in his onCreate(..) he didn't call it

Comment: I noticed, but the issue is not that the progressbar doesn't show up, it is that the OP is trying to access the progressbar from a different class. It is not even an Android-related question, it is a basic java/oop question about accessing properties of one instance into another.